# ActiveStorage: TypeError Exception: no implicit conversion of String into Hash

Tags: rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7, rails7

After Rails update from 6.1 to 7.0.3, I start getting ActiveStorage errors while calling something like

```
object.document_attachment.url
```

it throws the error `*** TypeError Exception: no implicit conversion of String into Hash`

One quick solution is

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(object.document_attachment.attachment, only_path: true)
```

but I am not in the favor of that, looking for the actual reason for the change.